# Increasing a Volume

Tags: ubuntu, partition, x-server

I used Gparted Live cd to resize a volume group and logical partition when i reboot and try to use `lvextend –l +100%FREE /dev/vda5` i get this message :

```
  Path required for Logical Volume "–l"
  Please provide a volume group name
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

Here is my `pvs` , `lvs` , `vgs` output :

```
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  d8dev-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 9.76g 5.01g
```

---

```
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/vda5  d8dev-vg lvm2 a--  9.76g 5.01g
```

---

```
  LV     VG       Attr      LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   d8dev-vg -wi-ao---    3.75g
  swap_1 d8dev-vg -wi-ao--- 1020.00m
```

and here is `df -h` output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  632K   99M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            498M  184K  497M   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/vda1       236M   37M  188M  17% /boot
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a5516e7a4136a510a3b6b388a57b266067cce4b2240db77a859910d3c741f988
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f5c852ead8bd3578b63fd5a259586c5a9c4b375b8505bb339e9f3c27cabc130f/shm
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/074360c189d2dae1477d9eeed419a86880355cab68c266155eb649aaee9e80ff
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/921ae5230e127989f8f12ecbd52a454965ed385531397fc46cfc5a82392ec876
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/eda6cf31040113c7216c4e07071596c724288071a94869b3606e90ea9fdc6034
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/27d44748763ef03fea24464e11dde5498329ce438002812cc5168379825c5003/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7a79506bb707843b3eea9d062f934e5f53a8ca72326a497559b0cd391f5f271b/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/78fbe6d2bccc7d29f08051a9ab4d2f02b0794fd7a95e28446e208184fa84b149/shm
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d06efbeda0bcf8352e88aa078d23caf3855ae14dbd9100980c3431dfce5870a7
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/10dd1eb657163fb314d1fd5e7951645e957365b9760b46846491c8374e106039
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/90a5ef4a9a761778fbad4bd052426263f5fe14d5248aaf7cdecd87013fb2c706/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/dd20465dc2764916efb2d29887dfe76d3bf8cf823b9e032d7ec399aa40dc083f/shm
none            3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/966dc571c622e09757ceebbfefd540a6ab4b27922b2fbab8615277e343a67357
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/312cceb4eb20613ad493df37097ab47a204da19669c3aa065feb7fc9818c126c/shm
```

I tried this commands

```
  lvextend –l +100%FREE /dev/vda5
  lvextend –l +100%FREE d8dev-vg
  lvextend –l +100%FREE /dev/root
```

But all same output

```
  Path required for Logical Volume "–l"
  Please provide a volume group name
```

**EDIT :** I did `lvextend /dev/dm-0 /dev/vda5` now my `lvs` output is :

```
  LV     VG       Attr      LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   d8dev-vg -wi-ao---    8.76g
  swap_1 d8dev-vg -wi-ao--- 1020.00m
```

But `/dev/dm-0` still is low :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  632K   99M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /
```

**EDIT 2** : `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` :

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               d8dev-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               9.76 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2498
  Alloc PE / Size       2498 / 9.76 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               AGVHqT-IO1R-l3uB-AeN4-q62b-z33r-b4NwS7
```

---

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/d8dev-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                d8dev-vg
  LV UUID                qet8dK-Izh1-uJul-2T0R-rDyy-ONNH-Xwvs2h
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time d8dev, 2016-05-19 08:17:01 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.76 GiB
  Current LE             2243
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/d8dev-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                d8dev-vg
  LV UUID                4mbhDG-PmAN-Fym3-yXSI-gRkd-owki-eYqWqj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time d8dev, 2016-05-19 08:17:01 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1020.00 MiB
  Current LE             255
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

**DF -Th**

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     100M  632K   99M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0      ext4      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     498M  184K  497M   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/vda1      ext2      236M   37M  188M  17% /boot
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a5516e7a4136a510a3b6b388a57b266067cce4b2240db77a859910d3c741f988
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f5c852ead8bd3578b63fd5a259586c5a9c4b375b8505bb339e9f3c27cabc130f/shm
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/074360c189d2dae1477d9eeed419a86880355cab68c266155eb649aaee9e80ff
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/921ae5230e127989f8f12ecbd52a454965ed385531397fc46cfc5a82392ec876
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/eda6cf31040113c7216c4e07071596c724288071a94869b3606e90ea9fdc6034
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/27d44748763ef03fea24464e11dde5498329ce438002812cc5168379825c5003/shm
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7a79506bb707843b3eea9d062f934e5f53a8ca72326a497559b0cd391f5f271b/shm
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/78fbe6d2bccc7d29f08051a9ab4d2f02b0794fd7a95e28446e208184fa84b149/shm
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d06efbeda0bcf8352e88aa078d23caf3855ae14dbd9100980c3431dfce5870a7
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/10dd1eb657163fb314d1fd5e7951645e957365b9760b46846491c8374e106039
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/90a5ef4a9a761778fbad4bd052426263f5fe14d5248aaf7cdecd87013fb2c706/shm
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/dd20465dc2764916efb2d29887dfe76d3bf8cf823b9e032d7ec399aa40dc083f/shm
none           aufs      3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/966dc571c622e09757ceebbfefd540a6ab4b27922b2fbab8615277e343a67357
shm            tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/312cceb4eb20613ad493df37097ab47a204da19669c3aa065feb7fc9818c126c/shm
```

Comment: Have you tried `lvextend -l +100%FREE root` ? What you want to achieve might in fact be `lvextend /dev/d8dev-vg/root /dev/vda5` .

Comment: @Nasha i did `lvextend /dev/d8dev-vg/root /dev/vda5` and output is `Extending logical volume root to 8.76 GiB` but  `/dev/dm-0       3.7G  3.2G  325M  91% /` still filled , i wanted to add space to `/`

Comment: @Synxmax you extended the Logical Volume but not the File system. You need to use `xfs_growfs`  for `xfs` partitioned lv's or `resize2fs`.  This can be done on a mounted drive

Comment: @val0x00ff man i don't have any clue on linux partitioning , could you be more specific and give me a example on my case

Comment: @Synxmax update the question and show the output of `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`.  You want to extend the root partition `/` correct?

Comment: Can you update  the output of `df` using `df -Th` ?

Comment: @val0x00ff I just added , yes i want to add space to `/`

Comment: @Synxmax  now run  `resize2fs /dev/d8dev-vg/root`  and you should be fine

Comment: @val0x00ff thanks man , did the trick :) , could you please post it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Glad you solved it. I've posted the answer. See if this somehow helps you in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with LVM (Logical Volume Manager) you should bear in mind that the order of operation is imperative. If you do not follow the order you risk losing your data.

If you already have a `PV`(Physical Volume) and a `VG`(Volume Group) it is easier to extend the volume group by adding additional devices.

To extend the volume group e.g `vg1` you can do the following:

```
vgextend vg1 /dev/vda5
```

After extending the volume group, we need to resize our `LV`(Logical Volume)

To extend the `LV` you can use the following

```
lvextend /dev/vg1/your_lv /dev/vda5
```

At this stage, only the logical volume has been extended, but not the file system.

To extend the file system, you can use `resize2fs` followed by the path to the `LV`. For example:

```
resize2fs /dev/vg1/your_lv
```

Note: `lvextend` has the `-r` flag which calls `resize2fs` in the background and does this operation automatically.

To summarize the above:

1. Extend the Volume Group
2. Extend the Logical Volume
3. Resize the file system

To shrink a file system (not possible with `xfs`) you follow the following procedure:

1. Shrink the file system
2. Reduce the size of the Logical Volume
3. Remove the device e.g `/dev/vda5` from the Volume Group

Comment: WOW you are the best , I'm sure this post will help so many people , Thanks again